# Display images from xml file to php

Tags: php, xml

I am new in PHP and XML.

I'm trying to make an e-shop where I have XML files as "database". In fact one XML for each product.

I display the data with PHP and everything seems to be going well except the images. When I'm trying to display the images in the `image td` it shows the path of the image and not the image.

PHP code

```
<?php
    $files =glob('*.xml');
    foreach($files as $file){
        $xml=new SimpleXMLElement($file, 0, true);
        $xpath = $xml->xpath("/wine/image");
?>                              
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $xml->id ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $xml->category ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $xml->name ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $xml->producer ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $xml->price ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $xpath[0]['src']; ?></td>                            
</tr>  
<?php
    }
?>
```

data.xml

```
<wine>
    <category>red</category>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>krasaki</name>
    <producer>alkoolikos</producer>
    <price>12.50</price>
    <addcart>patato</addcart>
    <image   src="images/white_wine.jpg" width="50" height="50"  /> 
</wine>
```

And `wine` is the root tag of the XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the image tag in the xml to img you could use

```
$xml->img->asXML();
```

to display the image.

You can also do a str_replace to replace the tag:

```
str_replace('image','img',$xml->image->asXML());
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem was solved in this thread. Have a look at this,

[How to display image in PHP with XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572299/how-to-display-image-in-php-with-xml)